# How to synthesize 1,1,1-trichloro-2,4-dimethylpentan-2-ol from methyl isobutyl ketone?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, alcohols

[Chlorobutanol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorobutanol) can be made with chloroform and acetone in the presence of potassium or sodium hydroxide. Would it work with other ketones such as [methyl isobutyl ketone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methyl_isobutyl_ketone) to yield 1,1,1-trichloro-2,4-dimethylpentan-2-ol?

[image: 4-methylpentan-2-one to 1,1,1-trichloro-2,4-dimethylpentan-2-ol]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chloroform anion generated with powdered KOH reacts with ketones to give addition resulting in the trichloromethyl methyl carbinol as reported by Willgerodt in 1881  (Chem. Berichte vol 14 245-60) as referenced here [source](https://krex.k-state.edu/dspace/bitstream/handle/2097/24699/LD2668T41951I4.pdf?sequence=1) which mentions that it has been extended to a wide range of ketones and aldehydes. So the direct reaction of methylisobutyl ketone with chloroform/KOH will give you your target compound.